# Wireless Card Not Sending Beacons During Heavy Traffic

Tags: linux, wifi, iwlwifi

I am using an Intel AX210 wireless card as an AP (actually a Wifi P2P Group Owner [GO]).  However, I'm having trouble with it, because it seems like it is not sending beacon frames when there is high traffic, which is causing some clients to disconnect and reconnect repeatedly.  For the moment I'm trying to work around the issue by having very short beacon intervals (i.e., 25ms), but I would like to find the root source of the problem.

My main problem is that I don't know what level this occurs at.  Is this a problem with wpa_supplicant?  The iwlwifi driver?  The firmware on the AX210?  The chip itself?

I'm trying to see if there is a real fix rather than just set the beacon interval really short, as this just papers over the problem (and doesn't guarantee it won't show up again).

Comment: I've read somewhere that `AX210`s aren't suited for being an AP - I think it was the OpenWRT forum, and lets face it, they would know about suitable AP devices

Comment: @JaromandaX - if you could find a reference, I would appreciate it.  This is being sold on products that are advertised as "IOT Gateways".

Comment: no reference - just discussion on OpenWRT forum about the inadequacies of that device - e.g. can only be a 2.4GHz Access Point without some *hacks* - is limited to about 20 clients MAX - etc, etc - just search openwrt forum - of course it may be an openwrt limitation, which you're not using, so I'm probably wrong

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with how it works on the stack involving the AX210, but as basically any modern Wifi card, that's SoftMAC, so your software is responsible for scheduling beacons. Sounds like under high traffic, there's some things that need to be replied to before it comes around to sending beacons.